# Galaxy S2 does not return signal correctly

Tags: android

Good morning!

I use this code to get signal of telecom network:

```
int signalof = signalStrength.getGsmSignalStrength();
```

The documentation says that 99 is returned when it was not possible to "read" the signal.

However, other devices, returns the value correctly.

**Only Galaxy S2 does not work. Versions 2.3.3 and 2.3.5 (Android factory build)**

Has anyone solved this problem?

Very Thanks!

Comment: always returns 99 or just more than other devices ?

Comment: Only in Galaxy S2 device always returns 99... :-(

Comment: and you are sure that your Galaxy S2 is a GSM/UMTS phone ? In other words: it is not a CDMA phone.

Comment: Dears? I'm not solve this yet... :-S